# loop through subdirectories and ffplay all mp3 files

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, shell, mp3

hi i'm trying to iterate through subdirectories and ffplay all MP3s in subdirectories, but i keep having only one track playing after it stops, here is my code

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar nullglob dotglob
cd /home/user/AUDIO
find . -wholename "*/*.mp3" | while read line; do
  TITLE=$(ffprobe -loglevel error -show_entries format_tags=title -of default=nw=1:nk=1 "$line")
  ARTIST=$(ffprobe -loglevel error -show_entries format_tags=artist -of default=nw=1:nk=1 "$line")
  DURATION=$(ffprobe -loglevel error -show_entries format=duration -of default=nw=1:nk=1 "$line")
  playCMD=$(ffplay -i "$line")
  if bash -c "$playCMD"; then
  echo "PLAYING NOW\!\!\! Track: $TITLE Title: $ARTIST Duration: $DURATION"
  else
  echo "nothing to play"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add `-autoexit` to the `ffplay` options.

Now, why the `bash -c` instead of just `ffplay -autoexit -i "$line"`?

And since you are using bash you can replace your loop by:

```
for f in **/*.mp3
do 
    TITLE=
    ...
        echo "PLAYING NOW\!\!\! Track: $TITLE Title: $ARTIST Duration: $DURATION"
    else
        echo "nothing to play"
    fi
done
```

Comment: … and only then `shopt` matters (it doesn't matter in the OP's code). The original `bash -c` fragment is even worse than one might think, because it is supposed to run the *output* from `ffplay` (stored in a variable).

Comment: thank you for your answer what about ffmpeg also i can use -autoexit option